# Rate of change of a normalised wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm reading Weinberg's Lectures on QM. On top of p23 it says
$$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\int|\psi(x,t)|^2d^3x=i\hbar\int\psi^*(x,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(x)d^3x-i\hbar\int\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi^*(x,t)\right)\psi(x)d^3x.$$

I'm confused about why the second term has a minus sign and why $\psi=\psi(x)$ only.

Comment: Comments to the question (v1): 1. There is no minus sign in the second term in Weinberg's 2013 book uploaded to [Google books](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=google+books+lectures+on+quantum+mechanics+weinberg). 2. $\psi(x)$ instead of $\psi(x,t)$ is a typo.

Comment: I agree. It's just strange that Weinberg makes such mistakes...

Comment: Related meta post: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6111/2451

Comment: Didn't know that there's a new edition!... Apparently mine is dated 2013 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that both are typos.

The honest calculation should read
\begin{align}
  i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}&\int|\psi(\mathbf x, t)|^2\, d^3x \\
&= i\hbar\int\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big(\psi^*(\mathbf x, t)\psi(\mathbf x, t)\Big)\, d^3x \\
&= i\hbar\int \left(\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial t}(\mathbf x,t)\psi(\mathbf x, t) + \psi^*(\mathbf x,t)\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}(\mathbf x,t)\right) \, d^3 x \\
&= \int \left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}(\mathbf x, t)\right)^*\psi(\mathbf x,t) \,d^3 x + \int\psi^*(\mathbf x,t)\left(i\hbar\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}(\mathbf x,t)\right)d^3x \\
&= -\int (H\psi)^*(\mathbf x,t)\psi(\mathbf x,t)\,d^3x + \int\psi^*(\mathbf x,t)(H\psi)(\mathbf x,t)\,d^3x \\
&= -\int\psi^*(\mathbf x,t)(H\psi)(\mathbf x,t)\,d^3x+ \int\psi^*(\mathbf x,t)(H\psi)(\mathbf x,t)\,d^3x \\
&= 0.
\end{align}

Comment: This looks good. It's just strange that Weinberg makes such mistakes...

Comment: @LorentzNoether Agreed.  I have found other typos in the book as well; I think he was a bit sloppy with this one.  In particular, I recall seeing some errors that were a lot worse than just incorrect signs in the section on constrained Hamiltonian mechanics.  So beware!  I actually emailed him about it, but never got a response.  I almost feel like we should start a question that catalogs errors like this, but I don't know if such a thing is allowed on SE.